# Fill area between Bezier curves in Bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

I am trying to create a sankey plot using `bokeh` and am currently trying to figure out how to fill an area between two `Bezier` curves. Is this possible or is there any alternative way to achieve this without adding the individual `Bezier` glyphs?

Example code below -- the goal would be to fill the area between the curves in orange.

```
from bokeh.models import Range1d, Plot, LinearAxis
from bokeh.models.glyphs import Bezier
from bokeh.io import show

plot = Plot(title=None, x_range=Range1d(0, 1), y_range=Range1d(-1, 1), plot_width=300, plot_height=300)

glyph = Bezier(x0=0, y0=0, x1=1, y1=1, cx0=0.5, cy0=0.01, cx1=0.5, cy1=0.99, line_color="orange", line_width=2)
glyph2 = Bezier(x0=0, y0=-1, x1=1, y1=0.5, cx0=0.5, cy0=-0.99, cx1=0.5, cy1=0.49, line_color="orange", line_width=2)

g1 = plot.add_glyph(glyph)
g2 = plot.add_glyph(glyph2)

xaxis = LinearAxis()
plot.add_layout(xaxis, 'below')

yaxis = LinearAxis()
plot.add_layout(yaxis, 'left')

show(plot)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Bokeh `0.13.0` there is no way to fill between two Bézier curves, using any built-in capability. Currently, to achieve this, you would have to write some sort of [custom extension class](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/extensions.html) that took your input data and drew the curves and filled between using the HTML Canvas JavaScript API.

Otherwise, the next closest thing, if you are able to represent the curves as explicit polylines instead of Bézier curves, is the [`Band`](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/annotations.html#bands) annotation. Assuming a data frame with `x`, `y_mean`, and `y_std`, you can do things like:

```
df['lower'] = df.y_mean - df.y_std
df['upper'] = df.y_mean + df.y_std

source = ColumnDataSource(df.reset_index())

band = Band(base='x', lower='lower', upper='upper', source=source, 
            level='underlay', fill_alpha=1.0, line_width=1, line_color='black')
p.add_layout(band)
```

[image]

It might be possible to consider adding a more general band that can be specified by things like Bézier curves. Feel free to make a [GitHb feature request issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues)